# Meaning of doubled method call with arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this line here:

```
ex.format(’order’).format(’third’, ’second’, ’first’)
```

How is this double call of 'format' called? How to implement this?
The plan is to check an argument if its 'order' and then arrange a new string made by the words 'third', 'second', 'first'.
But I have no idea how to implement it. I even cant find how this is called.

Please give me a simple example.
Single class with the method meow and the method call:

```
meow("two times").meow("a", "b", "c")
meow("one time").meow("a", "b", "c")

and output: abcabc
and output: abc
```

Comment: This gets evaluated from left to right, `x.something().something_else()` would be `(x.something()).something_else()` -> `(resulting_object_from_first_call).something_else()`

Comment: `str.format` returns `str`, which means you can call `.format` on that result

Comment: For this to work, format() must return an object containing method format(). You then call the format() method on the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "method chaining", and makes sense when the first method call returns an object which the second method can be called on.

In your example, if `ex` is a string then `ex.format('order')` is another string, so its `.format` method can be called immediately to produce yet another string.

The code you suggest doesn't make so much sense because firstly, you are passing a string with a number written in words where it would make sense to pass a number as an `int`; and secondly, a single `meow` method cannot (or at least, should not) both set the number of repetitions and *also* produce a string repeated a previously-set number of times. However, it *is* possible to achieve the behaviour you ask by writing two separate methods (actually, a function and a method):

```py
def meow(n):
    return Repeater(n)

class Repeater:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def meow(self, *strings):
        return ''.join(strings) * self.n
```

Usage:

```py
>>> meow(2).meow('a', 'b', 'c')
'abcabc'
>>> meow(1).meow('a', 'b', 'c')
'abc'
```

Comment: Thank you! So can you please give me an example how to write my first one with format? I wanna test if its called with 'order' and execute the same method with a precedure to sort the following strings and return them at the end.

Comment: You can't do `some_string.format(...).some_other_method_you_created(...)` because `.format` returns a string, and you cannot add new methods to the built-in `str` class.

Comment: The second method in the chain must be a method on the object that the first method returns. Since the first `format` method returns a string, the second method must be one which a string has.